# Angular 2: Populate checkbox list with HTTP response

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 2 for my web application. Now I am trying to populate a checkbox list from backend service call. This is what I am trying.

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap}        from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {DataService} from './service'
import {AppComponent}     from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,HTTP_PROVIDERS,DataService]);
```

**service.ts**

```
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http'
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  http: Http;
  constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  getCheckboxList() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/test/getList').map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }

}
```

**checkbox.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {DataService} from '../service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'views/checkboxlist.html'
})

export class CheckboxComponent {
  message = "hello";
  constructor(dataService: DataService) {
    dataService.getCheckboxList().subscribe(function(res) {
        console.log(res.result);
        this.list = res.result;
        console.log(this.list);

    })
  }
}
```

**checkboxlist.html**

```
<div>
  <label *ngFor="#item of list">
    <input type="checkbox">{{item.value}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Backend service is successful and returns a response and line **console.log(this.list);** prints an object array (HTTP response). Although, it doesn't display the checkbox list and there is not any error on the console log.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong with my code?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an arrow function in your component to be able to use the lexical this. In this case, the `this` keyword will correspond to the instance of the component. In your case, you use a "normal" function and the `this` keyword used in it doesn't correspond to the component instance...

```
dataService.getCheckboxList().subscribe((res) => { // <--------
    console.log(res.result);
    this.list = res.result;
    console.log(this.list);

})
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/r1kQXlBVYvuO5fvQJgcb?p=preview.

See this link for more details:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
        this.dataService.getCheckboxList().subscribe((res) => {
            console.log(res.result);
            this.list= res.result;
            console.log(this.list);
            
        })
    }When I use above code segment it gives a compile error as **Property 'list' does not exist on type 'CheckboxComponent'**

Comment: It's working.. needed to add selector under @Component

Comment: You need to add explicitly a property to your `CheckboxComponent` class to remove the error. Something like that: `private list:{value:string};`.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect an error message in the browser console

Try the safe-navigation `?.`

```
<input type="checkbox">{{item?.value}}
```

Comment: You also need to apply the change proposed by Thierry.